# Binding EasingColorKeyframe Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, animation

I made a simple animation using Expression Blend. the problem is that I can't figure how to bind the values of each Key Frame, blend won't let me do that, and after changing the XAML it seems as if the binding dose not work as I expect it should.

Here is the XAML:

```
  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames  RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="mainToggleButton">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=LowColor}"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=HighColor}"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=HighColor}"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"   Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=LowColor}"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=HighColor}"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Here are the DependencyProperties in the code behind

```
        [Category("Flash")]
        public Brush HighColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(HighColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HighColorProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HighColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HighColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HighColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(AttentionControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.LightGreen));


        [Category("Flash")]
        public Brush LowColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(LowColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LowColorProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LowColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LowColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LowColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(AttentionControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.DarkGreen));
```

The animation will work, but the binding dose not work, it seems as if the color dose not change trough the animation.

Thanks.

Comment: And the binding itself works without [errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)?

Comment: I've made sure that Data Binding Warning is selected and there are no errors at all, not in Blend or Visual Studio.

Comment: This works just fine for me, the color is not visible very long though. You are sure it isn't there, right?

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it dose work.  but it seems as if the colors won't change during the animation.  the background of the control is black, and when the animation is playing the text become invisible (black). but then at very few first milliseconds of the animation I can see the text.

I suspect that I have a problem with the value that I assign and not with the animation?

(I've updated my post with the code behind and the new XAML that I'm using)

Comment: UPDATE: It seems like It is impossible to bind such properties for this type of animation. it appears the the value will always be 0 when doing such bindings. I'm not sure about that, but from reading a few blogs, that seems to be the case.

Comment: I can bind the keyframe color just fine...

Answer (score 0):

The animation seems to be alright, 
I would test it on a transparent background so you can see all the colours if any .... 
Also I am not able to find an overall duration and begin time for each key frame ( i doubt that is the problem) but you never know, 
Its definitly worth having a go.